# Using R S4 classes, how can I overload the constructor?

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

Using R S4 classes, how can I write a pair of constructors that don’t take all slots arguments?

Given:

```
setClass("MyClass", slots = list(a = "list", b = "vector", c = "data.frame"))
#' Full data constructor
setMethod("initialize", "MyClass", function(.Object,
  a = "list",
  b = "vector",
  c = "data.frame", ...
) {
  .Object@a = a
  .Object@b = b
  .Object@c = c
  .Object
})
```

this works:
`o1 = new("MyClass", a = list(value=3), c=data.frame())`

I want to add a refined constructor able to add some logic on the internal representation:

```
setMethod("initialize",
  signature = "MyClass",
  function(.Object, some_other_parameter = "numeric") {
    # do some construction logic based on some_other_parameter
    new("MyClass",
        a = list(some_other_parameter = some_other_parameter),
        b = c(1,2,3),
        c = data.frame()
    )
  }
)
```

The new call doesn't work:
`o2 = new("MyClass", some_other_parameter = 3)`

and that is because this doesn't work any more:
`o3 = new("MyClass", a = list(value=3), c=data.frame())`

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

```
setClass("MyClass", slots = list(a = "list", b = "vector", c = "data.frame"))
setMethod("initialize", "MyClass", function(.Object,
                                            a = list(),
                                            b = vector(mode = "numeric"),
                                            c = data.frame(), 
                                            some_other_parameter = 3, ...) {
    # Do your construction logic here
    a1 <- a
    b1 <- if (some_other_parameter == 3) b + 3 else b
    c1 <- c
    
    .Object@a <- a1
    .Object@b <- b1
    .Object@c <- c1
    .Object
})
o1 <- new("MyClass", a = list(value=3), c=data.frame(), b = c(2, 4), some_other_parameter = 3)
```

## Explain

`new` function will call the `initialize` method for that class. For the specific you can read the "Description" section of `?new`. Furthermore, typing `new` without brackets to R console will print out the function body

```
new <- function(Class, ...) {
    ClassDef <- getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) # Get the Class definition
    value <- .Call(C_new_object, ClassDef) # Create an S4 object with the initial value as specified per "prototype" argument of setClass
    initialize(value, ...) # Call initialize method with the above S4 object
}
```

Therefore, you shouldn't call `new` within your `initialize` method.
Another approach is to avoid writing `initialize` method completely and write a helper function like this:

```
setClass("MyClass", slots = list(a = "list", b = "vector", c = "data.frame"))
create_MyClass <- function(a = list(), 
                           b = vector(mode = "numeric"), 
                           c = data.frame(), 
                           some_other_parameter = 3, ...) {
    # do all preprocessing to get your desired values for slot a, b, c
    a1 <- a
    b1 <- if (some_other_parameter == 3) b + 3 else b
    c1 <- c
    
    new("MyClass", a = a1, b = b1, c = c1)
}

create_MyClass(a = list(value=4), c=data.frame(), b = c(1, 2), some_other_parameter = 3)
```

**P/S**: I think your default value for `initialize` method should change
From:

```
setMethod("initialize", "MyClass", function(.Object,
                                            a = "list",
                                            b = "vector",
                                            c = "data.frame", ...)
```

To:

```
setMethod("initialize", "MyClass", function(.Object,
                                            a = list(),
                                            b = vector(mode = "numeric"),
                                            c = data.frame(), ...)
```